# Slotting a SVG inside another SVG in a Web Component

Tags: javascript, svg, web-component, native-web-component

Here's a CodePen: https://codepen.io/neezer/pen/VwbZNYB

I want to slot a SVG inside another SVG in a custom web component, but each time I get a blank screen. In the example above, you can comment out all of the JS and see the red square that should appear in my custom web component. I know my browser supports `<slot>` because the [MDN examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots) work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: <slot> is an HTML element, not an SVG one. You'd need to insert it inside a foreignObject for it to work, but note that SVG has <use> elements that probably can fulfill your needs.

Comment: @Kaiido This is precisely the thing I was missing. If you post your comment as a solution, I'll happily accept. I can't use `<use>` for my use case, but `<foreignObject>` works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foreignObject` only works when the **user** of the `<svg-slot>`Web Component (JSWC)
includes a **valid** SVG:

```html
<svg-slot>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="500" height="500">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="15%" fill="green"></circle>
  </svg>
</svg-slot>
```

for the `<template>`:

```html
<template>
  <style>svg{width:40vw}</style>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="500" height="500">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" fill="red"></circle>
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <slot></slot>
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
</template>
```

The `<svg-slot>` Web Component code required:

```js
  customElements.define('svg-slot', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.attachShadow({mode:'open'})
          .append(document.querySelector('template').content.cloneNode(true));
    }
  });
```

---

#### But...

you want your Web Component users to write **minimal** *semantic* HTML:

```html
<svg-slots>
  <circle slot="foo" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="15%" fill="green"></circle>
  <circle slot="bar" cx="50%" cy="50%" r= "5%" fill="gold"></circle>
</svg-slots>
```

[image]

That needs some extra work in the `connectedCallback` of the Web Component

Because `<circle>` in **lightDOM** now are `Unknown HTML Elements`.

So you need an extra step to turn everything in **lightDOM** into SVG (correct SVG NameSpace)

Which can then be injected into the (template) SVG in **shadowDOM**

```html
<svg-slots>
  <circle slot="foo" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30%" fill="green"></circle>
  <circle slot="bar" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="10%" fill="gold"></circle>
</svg-slots>

<template>
  <style>svg{ height:180px }</style>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="500" height="500">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="red"></circle>
    <slot name="foo"></slot>
    <slot name="bar"></slot>
  </svg>
</template>

<script>
  customElements.define('svg-slots', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.attachShadow({mode:'open'})
          .append(document.querySelector('template').content.cloneNode(true));
      setTimeout(()=>{ // make sure innerHTML is parsed
        let svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg");
        svg.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        svg.querySelectorAll("*")
           .forEach(el =>
                    this
                      .shadowRoot
                      .querySelector(`slot[name="${el.getAttribute("slot")}"]`)
                      ?.replaceWith(el)
            )
      })
    }
  });
</script>
```

#### notes:

- using the `<slot>` element; but **not** its functionality; it can be any (unknown) element.
- the `connectedCallback` also fires when moving DOM nodes (eg. Drag Drop); you need extra code to prevent errors. `attachShadow` can be moved to the `constructor`
- Can be re-factored to **not** use shadowDOM; then all SVGs can be styled with **global CSS**
  but you will get a FOUC because `<svg-slots>` 'innerHTML' now is shown as regular DOM,
  not lightDOM (optionally reflected/slotted into shadowDOM)
- You can do a lot more with `Unknown HTML Elements`

  ```html
  <pie-chart>
    <slice size="90" stroke="green">HTML</slice>
    <slice size="1"  stroke="red">JavaScript</slice>
    <slice size="9"  stroke="blue">CSS</slice>
  </pie-chart>
  ```

  creates a full SVG Pie Chart;

  See:

  - https://dev.to/dannyengelman/what-web-technologies-are-required-to-draw-a-pie-chart-in-2021-spoiler-alert-a-standard-web-component-will-do-1j56
  - https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-components-using-unknownhtmlelements-for-better-semantic-html-5d8c

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. In my case the slotted elements are additional custom elements, all of which define valid SVG (with `xmlns`), so `foreignObject` is still my preferred solution. I distilled my example for the problem at hand. Nice to know about these other options, though!

Comment: foreignObject has more bugs than an ant-hill